# Template data type in function definition

Tags: haskell

I have two functions in my program:

```
getWidth :: Size -> GLint
getWidth (Size a b) = a

getXPos :: Position -> GLint
getXPos (Position a b) = a
```

I realized that those two functions are doing the same thing and the only difference is parameter type. Question is: how do i write such a generic function:

```
getFirst :: ANYTHING -> a
getFirst (ANYTHING a b) -> a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [type class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types) (although IMO it isn't a good idea to generalize these two functions):

```
class Dimension d where
    getX :: d -> GLint
    getY :: d -> GLint

instance Dimension Size where
    getX (Size x y) = x
    getY (Size x y) = y

instance Dimension Position where
    getX (Position x y) = x
    getY (Position x y) = y
```

If you just want to write less code, employ [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax):

```
data Size = Size { getWidth :: GLint, getHeight :: GLint }
data Position = Position { getXPos :: GLint, getYPos :: GLint }
```

Answer (score 7):

This is probably a little bit overkill for your problem, but maybe it'll be
useful for someone else that stumbles upon this question.

You can implement a truly generic function that works on any datatype that has
a single constructor with two fields by using [GHC's generic programming](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/generic-programming.html).

Let's look at the type signature first. You'd like to write a function such as

```
getFirst :: ANYTHING -> a
```

In Haskell, a type that can be "anything" is signified with a type variable
(just like the result type `a`), so let's write

```
getFirst :: t -> a
```

However, having a fully polymorphic type doesn't let us operate on the type in
any way since we can't make any assumptions about its internal structure.
Therefore we need to write in some constraints about the type `t`.

The second thing is that a polymorphic return type (the `a` above) means that the
return type is inferred based on the call site, essentially meaning that the caller is able
to "request" any possible type for the first field. This is clearly impossible,
since for example for `Size` the only valid return type is `GLint`. So we need
to declare the return type so that it depends on the type `t`.

```
getFirst :: (Generic t, GPair (Rep t)) => t -> FirstT (Rep t)
```

Now, this is a rather complicated type signature, but the essence is that for
any type `t` that is generic and has a generic representation `Rep t` that is
a valid, generic pair (`GPair`), we can access the first field of the pair
which has the type `FirstT (Rep t)`.

The type-class `GPair` can be defined like this

```
class GPair g where
    type FirstT g   -- type of the first field in the pair
    type SecondT g  -- type of the second field in the pair

    gGetFirst  :: g x -> FirstT g
    gGetSecond :: g x -> SecondT g
```

This type-class introduces the function `gGetFirst` and `gGetSecond` that do not
operate on the pair type itself but its generic representation. The type
delcarations `FirstT` and `SecondT` are so called associated type synonyms that
are part of the [TypeFamilies](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/type-families.html) language extension. What we declare here
is that `FirstT` and `SecondT` are a synonym for some existing, unknown type
that is determined by the type `g`.

The generic representations of types are wrapped in meta-data descriptions that
contain information such as the data type name, constructor names, record field
names etc. We are not going to need any of that information for this case, so
the first instance of `GPair` simply strips out the meta-data layer.

```
instance GPair f => GPair (M1 i c f) where
    type FirstT (M1 i c f) = FirstT f
    type SecondT (M1 i c f) = SecondT f

    gGetFirst  = gGetFirst . unM1
    gGetSecond = gGetSecond . unM1
```

Next we need to make an instance for the generic constuctor with two fields.

```
instance (GField l, GField r) => GPair (l :*: r) where
    type FirstT  (l :*: r) = FieldT l
    type SecondT (l :*: r) = FieldT r

    gGetFirst  (l :*: _) = gGet l
    gGetSecond (_ :*: r) = gGet r
```

And then we define the generic field type-class `GField` which operates on a
single field of the pair.

```
class GField g where
    type FieldT g

    gGet :: g x -> FieldT g
```

We strip out the meta-data layer from `GField` as we did above

```
instance GField f => GField (M1 i c f) where
    type FieldT (M1 i c f) = FieldT f

    gGet = gGet . unM1
```

And now we just need to add an instance for generic constructor fields.

```
instance GField (K1 r t) where
    type FieldT (K1 r t) = t

    gGet (K1 x) = x
```

Now we can implement the truly generic accessor functions `getFirst` and `getSecond`.

```
getFirst :: (Generic t, GPair (Rep t)) => t -> FirstT (Rep t)
getFirst = gGetFirst . from

getSecond :: (Generic t, GPair (Rep t)) => t -> SecondT (Rep t)
getSecond = gGetSecond . from
```

The function `from` is part of `GHC.Generics` and it converts a value to its
generic form. For this, the data types `Size` and `Position` need to implement
the `Generic` type-class.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

data Position = Position GLInt GLInt deriving Generic
data Size     = Size GLInt GLInt deriving Generic
```

Let's test it out:

```
> let sz = Size 1 2
> let pos = Position 4 6
> getFirst sz
1
> getSecond pos
6
```

The functions also work automatically for appropriate built-in types, such as
tuples:

```
> getSecond (1, "foo")
"foo"
```

Now, you might think that this is an awful lot of code for a simple, generic
function and that's a valid concern. However, in practice the generic instances are rather easy and quick to write once you are familiar with how the generic representation types are structured.

Also, the great thing about GHC's generic
programming is that it's completely type-safe (unlike, for example, the
reflection APIs in Java). This means that if you try to use the generic
functions with incompatible types, you get a compile time error instead of
a run-time exception.

For example:

```
a = getFirst (1,2,3) -- compile error because value has more than two fields

data Foo = Foo Int Int | Bar Float Float deriving Generic

b = getFirst $ Foo 1 2 -- compile error because the type has multiple constuctors
```

Here's the complete code for trying this out:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics

class GPair g where
    type FirstT g
    type SecondT g

    gGetFirst  :: g x -> FirstT g
    gGetSecond :: g x -> SecondT g

instance GPair f => GPair (M1 i c f) where
    type FirstT (M1 i c f) = FirstT f
    type SecondT (M1 i c f) = SecondT f

    gGetFirst  = gGetFirst . unM1
    gGetSecond = gGetSecond . unM1

instance (GField l, GField r) => GPair (l :*: r) where
    type FirstT (l :*: r) = FieldT l
    type SecondT (l :*: r) = FieldT r

    gGetFirst  (l :*: _) = gGet l
    gGetSecond (_ :*: r) = gGet r

class GField g where
    type FieldT g

    gGet :: g x -> FieldT g

instance GField f => GField (M1 i c f) where
    type FieldT (M1 i c f) = FieldT f

    gGet = gGet . unM1

instance GField (K1 r t) where
    type FieldT (K1 r t) = t

    gGet (K1 x) = x

getFirst :: (Generic t, GPair (Rep t)) => t -> FirstT (Rep t)
getFirst = gGetFirst . from

getSecond :: (Generic t, GPair (Rep t)) => t -> SecondT (Rep t)
getSecond = gGetSecond . from
```